Fantasy manga/manhua where the male MC is a mage who gets kicked out of his party and is tricked to become a slave
I’m looking for a manga/manhua that starts with a male mage MC getting kicked out of his party and after trying to help a young slave girl who stole his gold, thinking he is buying her for 10gold but he is tricked and he becomes a slave of the guy that owned the girl.
I think it was mentioned he may also only be able to use basic spells. Think one of them he fires crystal spikes which build up and eventually freeze the enemy

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Black and white.
